# when run npm install in vue project

Tags: npm, vuejs2

### node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.19.0/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.19.0 and node@12.13.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015 gyp ERR! find VS - not found gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8 gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! find VS ************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload. gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at: gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows gyp ERR! find VS ************************************************************** gyp ERR! find VS gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47) gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16 gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14) gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14 gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16 gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7 gyp ERR! stack at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:302:5) gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5) gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72" gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5 gyp ERR! not ok node-pre-gyp ERR! build error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\bin\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\racksoftwares\Desktop\vueapp\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1) npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! grpc@1.19.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.19.0 install script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\racksoftwares\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-30T13_24_00_614Z-debug.log

Comment: Please add some context to the question. Also, have you tried looking thru SO if there is already a solution to this?

Comment: Please add more context, this may be a node version issue, what version of node are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a version of gRPC that does not support the version of Node that you are using. To fix this, either upgrade to a newer version of gRPC or downgrade to an older version of Node.